# Setting up the favicon

Tags: php, html, favicon

I have following code for my header.php file, in the includes folder.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Health Mate</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>
     </head>
     <!-- Some more code-->
 </html>
```

I have pasted favicon.ico in the includes folder itself.Problem is the favicon is not setting up.Also If i redirect user to some site on submit button like yahoo.com . My site is taking favicon of yahoo. Please suggest some solution. Also tell me if favicon needs to be .ico file or it can be .png as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have necessary path needed to locate your favicon.ico image.

Eg: If your folder is structured this way:

```
/mysite
  /includes
     favicon.ico
  index.php
```

If you're going to use it in index.php you should include the necessary path needed like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="includes/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Note: for checking if your like get the path towards your icon image..
you could check your web page source code using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>. Then click the `href` path linked if it displays  the image it means your path is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `favicon.ico` in to root directory of your website such that anyone can access it by `yourdomain.com/favicon.ico`.  `yourdomain.com/includes/favicon.ico` will not work without a link tag.

If you can't put the favicon on the root folder for your domain then you have to use this code and change the `href` attribute to match the path to the favicon relative to the root of your site.  i.e. `/includes/favicon.ico`

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" type="image/ico" href="/includes/favicon.ico">
```

I would recommend converting the file to an actual .ico using http://www.icoconverter.com/ or some equivalent tool.